# Why does ACCEPT all for all destinations in iptables not allow port 8445?

Tags: linux, iptables, redhat, linux-networking

I have a test server which has the following IPtables configuration:

```
[root@rhel64 /]# iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

When I tried to access an application listening on port 8445, it was rejected. Once I added a rule to specifically allow tcp traffic to 8445, then I could access it. My question is why does the above configuration not allow port 8445 by default if I have the rule "ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere"?

Comment: Try running iptables --list -v. You will probably see that the ACCEPT all line is for your lo interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of a long standing design flaw with the `iptables` `-L`/`--list` command. The complete firewall rule is not shown unless you use the `-v`/`--verbose` option. Once you do this, you will see that that rule accepts all traffic - on the `lo` interface!